# Prove that if a property holds for a function on rationals and the function is continuous, the property must hold on all reals

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

The context in which the question arose was trying to prove that the exponential function is the unique continuous function with the property that $g(s + t) = g(s)g(t)$ for $s,t > 0$.

I have shown by induction that $g\left(\frac{m}{n}\right) = (g(1)^{\frac{m}{n}})$ for all rationals $ \frac{m}{n} \ge 0$. Now I want to infer that $g(x) = g(1)^x$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$. We know that $g$ is continuous and that every real can be arbitrarily approximated by rationals.

Comment: The simple fact to prove is that two continuous functions into a T2 space which agree on a dense subset  must in fact be equal everywhere.

Comment: ok thanks, also i should have noted that uniqueness only follows once we normalize g(1) = e as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\{q_n\}$ be a sequence of rationals, such that $q_n\to x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Then as $g$ is continuous, we have

$$g(x) = g\left(\lim_{n\to\infty} q_n\right) = \lim_{n\to\infty} g(q_n) = \lim_{n\to\infty} g(1)^{q_n} = g(1)^{\lim_{n\to\infty} q_n} =  g(1)^x.$$